# Library or API for inferring country/location based on submitted string?

Tags: python, django-models, geolocation, sanitization

I'm retroactively sanitizing a bunch of data for the Offer Drive product (http://offerletter.io/drive.html). I'm trying to normalize a freeform "location" field to determine if submitted locations fall in the United States (or not).

Values may vary in granularity, but all are "real", e.g.

`San Francisco, CA`
`Milwaukee`
`Bangalore`
My question is, is there a good way (some API or library) of normalizing these intelligently based on the user-submitted strings such that I can say:

```
normalized = GeoNormalize.normalize("San Francisco")
return normalized.country() == "United States"
```

I really like `chronyk` ( https://github.com/KoffeinFlummi/Chronyk ) and something like that for locations would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many, usually provided by mapping or GIS vendors.

For example the Google geocoding service accepts a string and returns a ranked set of locations in a standard format:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?csw=1#Geocoding

Yahoo has one too:

https://developer.yahoo.com/boss/geo/#overview

like I said, there are many, many. They are usually free for light usage, but will incur usage fees after a certain point.

Answer (score 2):

Try [geograpy3](https://pypi.org/project/geograpy3/).

If you use python 3.x and face problems during install, try:

```
    python3 -m pip3 install git+https://github.com/somnathrakshit/geograpy3.git
    python3 geograpy-nltk
```